# поиск по максимальному значению в MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Приложение Spring.
Имеется сущность:

```
User {
int city;
int age;
...}
```

У меня есть запрос на поиск объекта с максимальным значением age по всей таблице:

```
Optional<User> findFirstByOrderByAgeAsc();
```

Можно как-то исправить этот запрос, чтобы поиск производился только в пределах конкретного города (city)?

В документации [Spring Data MongoDB](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#reference) нашел такой пример:

```
List<User> findByFirstnameSortByAgeDesc(String firstname);
```

Но у меня Spring не дает построить аналогичный запрос:

```
List<Person> findByCitySortByAgeAsc(String city);
```